# iOS 6 app crashes in EAGLContext when displaying maps

Tags: objective-c, ios, opengl-es, ios6

We have an app that uses OpenGL and `MKMapView`. When we switched to iOS 6 it started crashing at `[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:]` with EXC_BAD_ACCESS whenever we tried to display a map after setting our own `EAGLContext`.

Comment: Hi Darren, does the backtrace end on `gpus_ReturnNotPermittedKillClient`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

iOS 6 maps are OpenGL based. Your app will crash if you don't call

`[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:nil]`

after you have set your own EAGLContext. We fixed our bug by putting the above call into the dealloc method of our class that was interacting with EAGLContext.

Comment: Same problem here (iOS 6.1.3). Your workaround reduces the crashes, but sadly doesn't eliminate it completely.

Comment: It does not work : I can systematically reproduce the crash on 6.1 .

Comment: saved my life, VLC was crashing after watching other camera providers