# sgxTextureGetImageRowBytes EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, cocoa, opengl-es

I'm working on an OpenGL ES 2 app for iOS. This morning (without changing any code) I started getting `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` thrown from `sgxTextureGetImageRowBytes`.

```
#0      0x32979c20 in sgxTextureGetImageRowBytes(GLDTextureRec*, 
#           unsigned int, unsigned int) ()
#1      0x32979bd2 in CalculateChunkPlaneSizes(GLDTextureRec*, 
#           int, unsigned int*, unsigned int*, unsigned int*, unsigned int*) ()
#2      0x3297c336 in sgxConfigureTexturePrivate(GLDTextureRec*) ()
#3      0x3297af88 in glrUpdateTexture ()
#4      0x341a56c0 in gldLoadFramebuffer ()
#5      0x38387bd4 in gleUpdateDrawFramebufferState ()
#6      0x382ffa60 in glClear_Exec ()
#7      0x001221ea in clear ()
```

Has anyone seen this error before?

---

**Edit**:
Looks like others have seen similar issue ( [iOS 6 Maps occasional Crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13514296/ios-6-maps-occasional-crash) ), but the accepted solution did not work for me (nor did it sound promising).

I've submitted a request to Apple Developer Technical Support (DTS).

Comment: I am having the same issue...any new solution?

Comment: @TimWalsh DTS recommended I just reboot everything (the iPad, the Macbook Pro that I'm coding on) when that happens. It seems to be a bug with either iOS or XCode causing this.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the issue with the iOS version.  The user was running on iPad 4, iOS 6.1.2, as soon as I upgraded to 6.1.3 the problem went away.  Hope this helps someone.

Thanks,
Tim

Comment: To upgrade would have likely required a restart.

Comment: Not sure how relevant this is after 6-7 months, but this crash is happening on 6.1.3 too. Upgrading to it is not enough, and it seems from a different StackOverflow entry that this might be related to a memory leak somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a `__block` for your `MKMapView`:

```
__block MKMapView *map = _mapView;
[map addAnnotations:nearbyPlaces];
```

Comment: My code doesn't make use of the maps API. Forcibly restarting the iPad (as recommended by DTS) resolved it.